# Is there a way to parse excel spreadsheets to xml(The spreadsheet contains paragraphs and tables) in Python?

Tags: python, excel, xml, vba

I thanks for sharing your time, and here's the problem I've faced below

**[Summary]**


I'm trying to give xml information to an excel spreadsheet report.
Here's the capture of the spreadsheet, and the desired output below.

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUIGP.png)

The desired output is as such.

```
<p>1. Title for Sheet1</p>
<p></p>
<p>Paragraph for Sheet1</p>
<p></p>
<p>Paragraph2 for Sheet1</p>
<p></p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>2019</th>
      <th>2020</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>2,500</td>
      <td>3,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>4,500</td>
      <td>6,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**[The problem]**


I've looked up ways to parse excel to xml, but I can't figure out how to separate paragraph values and table values within the spreadsheet.
I'm thinking of a logic to recognize cells as paragraphs 'if there's no value in column B' and if else, recognize them as tables.
There will be probably multiple paragraphs and tables in each sheet.

**[What I need]**

1. The best way to parse spreadsheets as such to xml
2. How to keep 'alignment', 'width' and 'height' format information(I want to contain them in the xml).
3. If possible, to get information on merged cell as well. I think the spreadsheet report will contain merged cells in some cases.

I'm looking for answers on Python, and also VBA if needed.
I really appreciate all your help, and hope you have a wonderful day.

Comment: You mention Python in the title but you added the VBA tag. Does that mean you are also looking for a potential VBA answer?

Comment: @DecimalTurn Yes, I haven't studied VBA, and only used copy and paste for the VBA scripts.. But I'm very open to VBA answers and am willing to study them if needed.

Comment: XML, or HTML ?  Your example looks like HTML.  What is the spec for capturing style information?

Comment: Note that there are no 'paragraphs' in excel, as all content is in a cell. It is up to you to interpret a row with content in only one cell as a paragraph.

Comment: @Tim Williams XML. The tags were just examples. I don’t have any desired spec info for styles, since the xml is to be read in a custom program. Sorry for the amibguous descriptions, I’m a beginner in everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spreadsheet is very complicated, so if you what to get more help, may provide more the detail.

You Need:

- **The best way** to parse spreadsheets as such to XML

  - What is your condition?

    - Is Excel mean Microsoft-Office, Google-Spreadsheet or ?
    - which [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Versions) of Excel can you accept?
    - What do you do if Excel contains the script? (VBA ...)
    - What do you do if the cell contains the formula?
    - What do you do if locking (or protected)?
    - Are you need to write something back to Excel. (probably not)
    - Are you care performance or not? (COM)
    - Are you want to handle particular text (for example, _x0020_ ,...)
      ...

I mean, if you want to talk about **the best**, please bound it with some condition. Otherwise is belongs to a personal view.

I give you a [link](http://www.python-excel.org/) so that you can see which library may helpful for you

---

I still give you an example (I assume the case as easy as possible) as below,

## test data

test_data.xlsx

[image]

*you can get it from this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dyjn2DGn-E9A0mS3w0Zo_s_-F1909idOtpnPPMaH4f0/edit?usp=sharing)*

## code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, ElementTree
from openpyxl.worksheet.merge import MergedCellRange
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import SheetFormatProperties
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
from openpyxl.workbook.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell.cell import Cell

from typing import Tuple, List, Union


def prettify(elem: Element):
    """
    https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html
    """
    rough_string = tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    re_parsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return re_parsed.toprettyxml(indent='    ')  # 4 space


TABLE_START_ROW = 10


def main():
    wb: Workbook = load_workbook('test_data.xlsx')

    root = Element('root')
    table = Element('table')
    tbody = Element('tbody')
    for sheet in [wb[sheet_name] for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames]:
        # print(sheet.title)
        sheet: Worksheet
        sheet_prop: SheetFormatProperties = sheet.sheet_format
        default_width = sheet_prop.baseColWidth
        default_height = sheet_prop.defaultRowHeight
        merge_cell_list: MergedCellRange = sheet.merged_cells.ranges
        for row in sheet.rows:
            if not any([cell.value for cell in row]):
                root.append(Element('p'))  # empty line
                continue

            cur_row = row[0].row
            if cur_row < TABLE_START_ROW:
                # `NOT TABLE` DATA
                data_list = []
                for cell in row:
                    cell: Cell
                    if cell.value:
                        merge_info: List[Union[None, MergedCellRange]] = [
                            merge_cell for merge_cell in filter(lambda merge_cell: cell.coordinate in merge_cell,
                                                                merge_cell_list)
                        ]

                        is_merge = len(merge_info) > 0
                        if is_merge:
                            # It should recalculate the width and height.
                            merge_range: MergedCellRange = merge_info[0]
                            size: dict = merge_range.size
                            num_col = size['columns']
                            num_row = size['rows']

                            width = 0
                            for idx in range(num_col):
                                width += sheet.column_dimensions[
                                    chr(ord(cell.column_letter)+idx)  # A B ...
                                ].width

                            height = 0
                            for idx in range(num_row):
                                new_height = sheet.row_dimensions[cell.row+idx].height
                                height += new_height if new_height else default_height

                        else:
                            width = sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width
                            height = sheet.row_dimensions[cell.row].height
                            height = default_height if height is None else height

                        merge_info: Union[Tuple[bool, str], List[None]] = \
                            (is_merge, merge_info[0].coord) if merge_info else [None]

                        align: Tuple[str, str] = (cell.alignment.horizontal, cell.alignment.vertical)
                        data_list.append((str(cell.value), align, (height, width), merge_info))

                p_list = []  # for the `div` tag
                for value, (text_align, vertical_align), (h, w), merge_info in data_list:
                    is_merge, *coord = merge_info
                    p = Element('p')
                    p.text = value
                    if text_align:
                        p.attrib['text_align'] = text_align
                        # show w and h only on align cells
                        p.attrib['width'] = str(w)
                        p.attrib['height'] = str(h)
                    if vertical_align:
                        p.attrib['vertical_align'] = vertical_align
                    if is_merge:
                        p.attrib['merge_coord'] = coord[0]
                    p_list.append(p)
                if len(data_list) > 1:
                    div = Element('div')
                    for tag_p in p_list:
                        div.append(tag_p)
                    root.append(div)
                else:
                    root.append(p_list[0])
            elif cur_row == TABLE_START_ROW:
                # TABLE HEADER
                thead = Element('thead')
                tr = Element('tr')
                thead.append(tr)
                for cell in row:
                    th = Element('th')
                    th.text = str(cell.value)
                    tr.append(th)
                table.append(thead)
                table.append(tbody)
                root.append(table)
            else:
                # TABLE ROW
                tr = Element('tr')
                for cell in row:
                    td = Element('td')
                    td.text = f'{cell.value:0,.0f}' if isinstance(cell.value, int) else str(cell.value)
                    tr.append(td)
                tbody.append(tr)

    if not 'output mode is compressed':
        tree = ElementTree(root)
        tree.write('result_compressed.xml')  # ugly (The output format compressed that is not easy for human reading.)
        return
    with open('result.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(prettify(root))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Test on Excel 2013 (v15.0)* | *Python 3.7.3* | *openpyxl 3.0.4*

## demo

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <p>1.Title for Sheet1</p>
    <p/>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph for Sheet1</p>
        <p>p1.sub.msg</p>
    </div>
    <p/>
    <p height="47.25" merge_coord="A5:B6" text_align="center" width="53.0">Paragraph2 for Sheet1 (merge)</p>
    <p/>
    <p/>
    <p height="36.75" text_align="right" vertical_align="center" width="33.0">align_right_vertical_center</p>
    <p/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>2019</th>
                <th>2020</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>2,500</td>
                <td>3,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>4,500</td>
                <td>6,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</root>
```

I add the `div` deliberately. It means they are in the same row.

Comment: I can limit the condition a lot as to my preference, since I can specify the spreadsheet template which my employees would use. Thanks so much for the time you've spent for writing the script and the example, and I'll study it from scratch to understand every bit. Thanks a lot, wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any great options for this, but here are 4 possibilities:

option 1. From excel, save as XML. You will then have to specify a mapping to the XML structure you want.

option 2. An xlsx file is actually a zipped XML file, so you can save an xlsx file (eg save to C:\temp\a.xlsx). Then, change the file extension to '.zip'. If you open the zip file there is a directory of files. The content of the first worksheet is in: C:\temp\a.zip\xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml

Use XSL to transform the XML to whatever structure you want. The XML contains the values and dimensions and style formatting (it is the spreadsheet).

There are other metadata files in the zipped directory as well.

option 3. From excel, Save as '.htm'. This html file actually a script, so you would probably want to open the html file in a browser, then save the html file again, to get the table you want.

option 4. Save as csv, then write a script to loop through each row of the csv and wrap the  round each row and  around each cell value. This is probably the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The tag names were just examples and xml is the desired output. I’m aware that there aren’t concepts such as paragraphs in excel, so I’m trying to define paragraphs as cells in rows with no value in column B. I was wondering if there would be a easier approach than breaking down the excel xml file itself, but I’ll try out what you’ve mentioned.

Comment: As a novice, I really like your csv solution, only if formatting doesn't matter. I'll look into into everything thanks again, you're awesome.